# How can you detect if an Intent was not launched due to multiple possible targets?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

If I launch an Intent via `activity.startActivity(intent)` and there are multiple apps which can handle the Intent, you get a dialog along the lines of "Complete action using:" followed by the list of apps.

How can I detect if they cancel this dialog (e.g. via the back button) back to the app, rather than select an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, unless you create your own chooser dialog (using data from `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`).

Comment: That's rather disappointing, but I suspected as much. Thanks.